# Live search in php

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<script>
function aa() {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","datafile.php?nm="+document.form1.t1.value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; }
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type="text" name="t1" OnKeyup="aa();" class="box" placeholder="You may search via Surname or Firstname">
<div id="d1"></div>
```

and in datafile.php

```
<?php include "konek.php";
$nm1=$_GET['nm']; ?>

<?php
$res=mysql_query("select * from tblscholar where schoSurname like ('$nm1%') OR schoFirstname like ('$nm1%') AND schoUsername != 'admin'; ");

$c=1;
while($fet=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{ ?>

<td width='55%'><a href="searchviewForAdmin.php?id=<?php echo $fet[0]?>"><?php echo $fet[1]; ?> , <?php echo $fet[2]; ?> <?php echo $fet[3]; ?></a></td>
```

The problem is, when i delete all of what i typed in the search bar all of the results are displaying

Comment: ... and your question is what exactly?

Comment: Can't you just do an if to see if $nm1 is empty? Then just `exit()`

Comment: When `$nm1` is empty, you're doing `WHERE schoSurname LIKE '%'`, which matches everything.

Comment: Check whether `document.form1.t1.value` is empty, and don't send the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to clear the data if the input field is empty:

```
function aa() {
   if (document.form1.t1.value.length == 0){
       document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = "";
       return ;
   }
   ... rest of your code ...
}
```

**Note 1:** mysql_* functions are depricated, use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or pdo

**Note 2:** Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Sanitize your input before using them in a query

On the php side:

```
<?php 
$nm1=$_GET['nm']; 

if (empty($nm1)){
   echo "no result";
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's returning everything because of this piece:

```
like ('$nm1%')
```

When `$nm1` is empty then your query is simply performing this:

```
like ('%') // Translates to 'get me everything from the table'
```

You need a logic checker which says:

```
if($nm1 !== '')
{
   // do query, echo HTML
}
else
{
    // do nothing
}
```